# Using markdown widget to show json data

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to display this data like this using flutter_markdown widget?
what property do I have to have a look at ?

[image]

[image]

```
  Container(
                height:300,
                child: Markdown(
                 data: entry.value.toString(),

                ),
              )
```

Comment: You could put that all into one string and display it on the flutter_markdown widget.

Comment: @YoungA:I am able to display it , using the markdown widget , but it is not being styled like in the format above. The data is grouped together like in the 2nd picture.

Comment: You need to put some whitespaces and new lines so that it could be styled like the first picture

Comment: Thanks . I realise I was approaching this wrong .I can use Json_viewer widget to show it in this format.